# Is this a good practice to check user input?

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin, cout, ostream

```
do {
    std::cout << "Enter a valid name" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> name;

} while (!validName(name) && std::cout << "It is not a valid name" << std::endl);
```

Is this a good practice tha if the name is not valid, then I respond with a line this way?

Comment: It is **always** necessary to check whether input was succesful, e.g.. using `while (std::cin >> name) { ... }`. If there are further constraints on `name` to constitute valid input, these should also be checked.

Comment: @ChrisK: _"1st of all use the using namespace std; so you dont have to add always the std"_ Mm no ideally quite the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably clearer to do the checking and output within the loop itself.  You can do this by breaking an infinite loop or continuing a one-time loop.  For example:

```
do {
    std::cout << "Enter a valid name" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> name;
    if (!validName(name)) {
        std::cout << "It is not a valid name" << std::endl;
        continue;
    }
} while (false);
```

Or the reverse:

```
for ( ;; ) {
    std::cout << "Enter a valid name" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> name;
    if (validName(name))
        break;

    std::cout << "It is not a valid name" << std::endl;
}
```

I generally prefer the second, since it makes it easy to inject a counter, so you can do some other type of error handling if the loop body fails more than a certain number of times.

```
for (int attempt = 0; attempt < 3; ++attempt) {
    std::cout << "Enter a valid name" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> name;
    if (validName(name))
        break;

    std::cout << "It is not a valid name" << std::endl;
}

if (!validName(name)) {
    std::cout << "Failed to get a valid name after 3 tries" << std::endl;
    std::abort();
}
```